# How to load the Classes within PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have been trying to load the various classes associated with PhpSpreadsheet, but am encountering many problems.

I have followed many postings and implemented spl_autoload_register using the following code:

```
function my_autoload($classname) {
    $fullclassname = $classname . '.php';
    include $fullclassname;
}

set_include_path(get_include_path()  . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/var/www/html/mywebsite/includes/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/');
spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet;
```

Unfortunately, all I every get is 'Class not found'.

I've discovered that a limitation of spl_autoload is that it requires everything to be in lower case.  As I understand it, this would require every directory name, file name, Class name and Namespace definition within PhpSpreadsheet to be modified.  Not a viable long term solution.

Another alternative is to hard-code include statements for each .php file within PhpSpreadsheet.  Again, not a viable long term solution.

Is there another option?

Comment: There's no way to handle that other than to hardcode cases like this in your `my_autoload()` function.

Comment: any reason why you don't use composer?

Comment: Another option is to use a [package manager](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet) like [composer](https://getcomposer.org) that allows you to use a single autoloader to load any of your libraries using PSR-0 and PSR-4 and is usually the suggested method of [installation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation).